# How to pass value in window.location?

Tags: c#, javascript, parameter-passing

I am trying to add QueryString something like this

```
var id = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML;
var subTypeId = e.row.cells[1].innerHTML;

window.location = "/Master/ReceivedStatus?Id=" + '@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString(id)' + "&SubTypeID=" + '@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString(subTypeId)';
```

@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString is expecting string value always and is a static class.

But it is showing error as id and subTypeId not exist in the current context. Is it possible to pass the value like this if yes then how?

Someone please help me and tell me how can I pass the value like this.

Comment: When do you expect that EncryptDecryptHelper to work? This seems like server-side Razor syntax, which generates javascript that must then be executed in the browser.

Comment: My code is in View and passing the value at server side and EncryptDecryptHelper will work at server side, I'll Decrypt the value in Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using below code and it working for me.

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("ReceivedStatus", "Master", new { Id =  '@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString(id)', SubTypeID = '@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString(subTypeId)'})';
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables need to be outside of the quotes;

```
window.location = '/Master/ReceivedStatus?Id=' + '@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString(' + id + ')&SubTypeID=@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString(' + subTypeId + ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use the variables id and subTypeId inside a string. You must escape the string to reference to the variable.

```
window.location = "/Master/ReceivedStatus?Id=" + '@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString(' + id + ')' + "&SubTypeID=" + '@EncryptDecryptHelper.EncryptString(' + subTypeId + ')';
```